# How do I disable dates till current date? For input Type Datetime-local

Tags: javascript, forms, datetime

I am using Modal for reminder date for task. The current date and the days before it has to be disabled so that the User can select the pick-up date starting next day inorder to Mark reminder with his specified task.

for this I am using input type :
 `<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="actionreminderdate" />`

If I use below java script it works for input type "Date" But not for Datetime-local.

```
$(function(){
    var dtToday = new Date();    
    var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = dtToday.getDate();
    var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
    if(month < 10)
       month = '0' + month.toString();
    if(day < 10)
       day = '0' + day.toString();

     var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
     /*alert(maxDate);*/
     $('#actionreminderdate').attr('min', maxDate);
});
```

Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set min and max values on the input field:

`<input type="datetime-local" id="dateInput">`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    elem = document.getElementById("dateInput")
    var iso = new Date().toISOString();
    var minDate = iso.substring(0,iso.length-1);
    elem.value = minDate
    elem.min = minDate
});
```

Get the current time in a recognised ISO format (you have to trim the zone data off the end, which is annoying), then set that as the input value and the input min.

https://jsfiddle.net/w8qgj543/24/

Comment: I tried this in fiddle on an ios device however it did not work.
Works well in android however.

Comment: @offwhite - this is not working in windows 10