# Disable previous today's previous time in html input datetime-local picker

Tags: javascript, html, datetimepicker

I am trying to figure out solution to fix the issue of not allowing user to select previous time. I mean for eg

Today's date: 17-02-2019
Current Time: 02:30 PM

So when user selects today's date and selects the time 02:30 AM instead of PM. Here the time is past so user shouldn’t be allowed to select the AM time because the current time is 02:30 PM

As per MDN docs the below code should work but it’s not working.

```
   <input type="datetime-local" min="2019-02-17T14:30" />
```

As per below docs it shouldn’t allow me to select time like eg 9:00 AM, 10:00 AM even 02:29 PM but I am allowed to select. I even tried their fiddle example but their examples do allow me to select past time

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

Answer (score 5):

This may be because of the format , you may need to strip off the seconds. In console.log you can see the seconds but when setting the `min` value the seconds and microseconds need to strip off

```js
var today = new Date().toISOString();
console.log(today)
document.getElementById("daTi").min = '2019-02-17T10:38';
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id='daTi' />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my question I don’t have seconds to min attribute I have only hours and minutes. It doesn’t work

Comment: This seems to work fine for me `min: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm")`. As per the MDN docs `If the value entered into the element is later than this timestamp, the element fails constraint validation.` I'd say if this doesn't work for you then your datetime string is wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50719733/4905826 This works for me

Comment: Can be programmatically done by `new Date().toISOString().substring(0,16)`