# I need to block previous dates in a calendar using JavaScript in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Need current date and time with previous dates blocked.
I am using this function for setting due date which cant be historic.
Previous dates in the calendar should be blocked but time can be anything.

TypeScript

```
currentDate: string;
constructor(private TodoService: TodoService) { }

ngOnInit() {this.currentDate = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];}
```

HTML

```
Due Date: <input id="date" [(ngModel)]='todo.DueDate' type="datetime-local" [min]="currentDate" name="date" ><br><br>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable previous today's previous time in html input datetime-local picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54732299/disable-previous-todays-previous-time-in-html-input-datetime-local-picker)

Comment: In brief, you can't. The only thing setting `min` does is make a date prior to that value an invalid value.

Comment: `<input type="datetime-local">` [is not supported on Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#Browser_compatibility). Perhaps you want to implement it with `type="date"` and `type='time'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

html

```
<input id="date" [(ngModel)]='dueDate' type="datetime-local" [min]="currentDate" name="date">
```

ts

```
currentDate: string;
constructor(private TodoService: TodoService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.currentDate = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 16);
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wndxf3?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: @Viraj Rajopadhye Try this now.